# не работают javascript скрипты до перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, angularjs

есть такая проблема.

Веб приложение на ангуляре.
Через ajax подгружается шаблон при клики по ссылке.
Я в него (в шаблон) вставил несколько DOM эллементов (форму, кнопка и txt input)

К ним привязан простой скрипт поиска по странице как ctrl+f
Проблема в том, что этот скрипт работает только первый раз, если нажат на другую ссылку (подгрузится другой шаблон) и потом вернуться обратно скрипт перестает работать, до обновления страницы (F5).

Сама форма которую я вставил, просто отображается при переходе по нужной ссылке и при уходе с нее скрывается `( .hide(); .show();)`

Т.е. скрипт работает только 1 раз получается потом, что-бы он работал, нужно перезагрузить страницу.

Сам скрипт обернут в `$(document).ready(function(){`

Вот сам скрипт:

```js
function hidefindmodule() {
  $('#search_block').hide();
  $('#search_text').val('');
  $('#search_block').css("z-index", "0");
  $("#search_block").css("position", "relative");
  $("#search_block").css("background-color", "#f3f3f3");
  $("#search_block").css("padding", "0px");
  $("#search_block").css("border-radius", "0px");
  $("#search_block").css("opacity", "1");
  $('#clear_button').hide('slow');
  $('#clear_button').hide('slow');

}

$(document).ready(function() {
      var search_number = 0;
      var search_count = 0;
      var count_text = 0;
      var srch_numb = 0;

      function scroll_to_word() {
        var pos = $('body .selectHighlight').position();
        $.scrollTo(".selectHighlight", 500, {
          offset: -150
        });
      }

      $('#search_text').on('keyup oncnange', function() {

        $('body').removeHighlight();
        txt = $('#search_text').val();
        if (txt == '') return;
        $('#clear_button').show('slow');

        $('body').highlight(txt);
        search_count = $('body span.highlight').length - 1;
        count_text = search_count + 1;
        search_number = -1;

        console.log("search_count" + search_count);
        console.log("search_count" + search_number);
        console.log("search_count" + count_text);
        console.log("search_count" + srch_numb);


        //$('body').selectHighlight(search_number);
        // if (search_count >= 0) scroll_to_word();

        $('#count').html('Найдено: <b>' + count_text + '</b>');

        $('ul').removeClass('ng-scope ng-hide');
        $('ul').addClass('ng-scope');
        //  $('#search_block').css("z-index", "50");
        //  $("#search_block").css("position", "fixed");
        //  $("#search_block").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
        //  $("#search_block").css("padding", "15px");
        //  $("#search_block").css("border-radius","6px");
        //  $("#search_block").css("opacity", "0.9");
      });

      $('#clear_button').click(function() {
        $('body').removeHighlight();
        $('#search_text').val('');
        $('#count').html('');
        jQuery.scrollTo(0, 500, {
          queue: true
        });
        $('#search_block').css("z-index", "0");
        $("#search_block").css("position", "relative");
        $("#search_block").css("background-color", "#f3f3f3");
        $("#search_block").css("padding", "0px");
        $("#search_block").css("border-radius", "0px");
        $("#search_block").css("opacity", "1");
        $('#clear_button').hide('slow');
        $('#clear_button').hide('slow');
        //  $('ul').removeClass('ng-scope');
        //  $('ul').addClass('ng-scope ng-hide');
      });

      $('#prev_search').click(function() {
        if (search_number == 0) return;
        $('body .selectHighlight').removeClass('selectHighlight');
        search_number--;
        srch_numb = search_number + 1;
        $('body').selectHighlight(search_number);
        if (search_count >= 0) {
          scroll_to_word();
          $('#count').html(srch_numb + '</b> из ' + $('body span.highlight').length);
        }
      });

      $('#next_search').click(function() {
        if ($('#search_text').val() == "") {
          $('.warnfindkis').show("slow");
        } else {
          $('.warnfindkis').hide("slow");
          var marker = 0;
          if (marker == 0) {
            $('#search_block').css("z-index", "50");
            $("#search_block").css("position", "fixed");
            $("#search_block").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
            $("#search_block").css("padding", "15px");
            $("#search_block").css("border-radius", "6px");
            $("#search_block").css("opacity", "0.9");
            marker = 1;
          }
          if (search_number == search_count) return;
          $('body .selectHighlight').removeClass('selectHighlight');
          console.log("search_count" + search_count);
          console.log("search_count" + search_number);
          console.log("search_count" + count_text);
          console.log("search_count" + srch_numb);
          search_number++;
          srch_numb = search_number + 1;
          $('body').selectHighlight(search_number);
          if (search_count >= 0) {
            scroll_to_word();
            $('#count').html(+srch_numb + '</b> из ' + $('body span.highlight').length);
          }
        }
      });

      console.log("search_count" + search_count);
      console.log("search_count" + search_number);
      console.log("search_count" + count_text);
      console.log("search_count" + srch_numb);

      $('#search_text').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
          if ($('#search_text').val() == "") {
            $('.warnfindkis').show("slow");
          } else {
            $('.warnfindkis').hide("slow");
            var marker = 0;
            if (marker == 0) {
              $('#search_block').css("z-index", "50");
              $("#search_block").css("position", "fixed");
              $("#search_block").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
              $("#search_block").css("padding", "15px");
              $("#search_block").css("border-radius", "6px");
              $("#search_block").css("opacity", "0.9");
              marker = 1;
            }
            if (search_number == search_count) return;
            $('body .selectHighlight').removeClass('selectHighlight');
            console.log("search_count" + search_count);
            console.log("search_count" + search_number);
            console.log("search_count" + count_text);
            console.log("search_count" + srch_numb);
            search_number++;
            srch_numb = search_number + 1;
            $('body').selectHighlight(search_number);
            if (search_count >= 0) {
              scroll_to_word();
              $('#count').html(+srch_numb + '</b> из ' + $('body span.highlight').length);
              $("#next_search ").focus()

            }
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: Задачи в ангулар приложении надо решать средствами ангулара! Не надо смешивать ангулар и jQuery.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko и все же, что это может быть )?

Comment: В том то и проблема, что когда смешиваются два разных подхода, то предсказать поведение трудно. Поэтому сложно ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Приведите код контроллера, что бы понять что происходит и где и как вызывается